# Determine sample size for two groups

Tags: sample-size

What is the minimum sample size needed to call a difference between two groups of 0.10 significant, when s=2.50 for both? Assume both groups are the same size. (You probably will need to do some algebra to answer this question.)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I really don't know where to start.  I understand it is based on a T test and then working backwards from there.

Comment: Ott/Longnecker: Intro to Stat Methods & Data Analysis, 7e shows aprx formula for 2-sided, 2-sample test: $ n \approx 2\sigma^2(z_{\alpha/2} + z_\beta)^2/\Delta^2,$ where $\alpha$ is Type I error probability, $\beta$ is Type II err. prob, $\Delta$ is difference in population means to be detected. (Ignores probability is smaller tail.) Can you derive it? This is for normal aprx with samples of at least moderate size. See normal approach in my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Various software packages have procedures for this. Here
is output from Minitab.

```
Power and Sample Size 

2-Sample t Test

Testing mean 1 = mean 2 (versus ≠)
Calculating power for mean 1 = mean 2 + difference
α = 0.05  Assumed standard deviation = 2.5. 


            Sample  Target
Difference    Size   Power  Actual Power
       0.1    9813    0.80      0.800039
       0.1   13136    0.90      0.900017
       0.1   16245    0.95      0.950007

The sample size is for each group.
```

[image]

---

From the instructions, it is clear that you are expected
to do this computation on your own. An exact answer
would  require use of a non-central t distribution.
You would have to try several sample sizes to see
the power for each.

However, notice that the required sample sizes are
large enough that you can assume the t statistic is
nearly normal. Also notice that the problem specifies
sample standard deviations not population standard deviations, which may be a clue the question is
targeted towards use of the normal distribution.

Your question did not specify level of significance
or the desired power. I used 5% significance level
and specified power .8, .9 and .95. The Minitab procedure provided sample sizes (in each group) to achieve each
specified power.